# Creating public properties in sandboxed webpart solutions

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution, properties, farm-solution

I'm trying to port a farm solution to a sandboxed one, and I can't figure out how to port this piece of code:

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public partial class vClockPartSB : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public Collection<String> ClockTimeZones { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public int NumberOfClocks { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public string DdlMain { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public string DdlSubOne { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public string DdlSubTwo { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public string DdlSubThree { get; set; }
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
    public string DdlSubFour { get; set; }



    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        ClockTimeZones = new Collection<string>();
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code
>   wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: Web part
>   property 'ClockTimeZones' uses unsupported type
>   (System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]),
>   and cannot be run as a sandboxed code web part.

How should I approach it?

Comment: And what about using a simple List<string> instead of Collection?

Comment: Same. Also with a simple array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted just to store a string - rather than a collection of strings - and perform my own serialisation/deserialisation. Probably using the string.Split() function and a suitable delimiter.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Bizarre. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but I did blog about a similar issue: http://www.novolocus.com/2012/04/05/spweb-properties-serialization-in-the-sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace is not allowed in the Sandbox.

For your scenario, could you use the [List< string >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead?

Comment: Nope, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, only the following types are supported as the properties of the web part in the sandbox solution:

- string
- bool
- Enum
- short
- int
- Guid
- Uri
- byte
- char
- long
- float
- decimal
- double

Here is a link to Alan Dahl's [blog article](http://blog.a-dahl.dk/post/A-limitation-on-Sandboxed-solutions-e28093-Webpart-properties.aspx) where Alan Dahls' blog did the search.